# Mapping to dataframes based on one column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df1) of 5 columns (a,b,c,d,e) with 6 rows and another dataframe (df2) with 2 columns (a,z) with 20000 rows.

How do I map and merge those dataframes using ('a') value.
So that df1 having 5 columns should map values in df2 having 2 columns with 'a' value and return a new df which has 6 columns (5 from df1 and 1 mapped row in df2) with 6 rows.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Can you confirm that 'a' is a unique identifier?

Comment: Go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101 and search for "Merging only a single column from one of the DataFrames".

Comment: yes 'a' is present in both the df1 and df2 . we have to map values using a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns_df1 = ['a','b','c','d']
columns_df2 = ['a','z']
data_df1 = [['abc','def','ghi','xyz'],['abc2','def2','ghi2','xyz2'],['abc3','def3','ghi3','xyz3'],['abc4','def4','ghi4','xyz4']]
data_df2 = [['a','z'],['a2','z2']]

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_df1, columns=columns_df1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_df2, columns=columns_df2)
print(df_1)
print(df_2)

frames = [df_1, df_2]

print (pd.concat(frames))
```

OUTPUT:
[image: out]

Edit:

To replace `NaN` values you could use [pandas.DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
print (pd.concat(frames).fillna("NULL"))
```

Replcae `NULL` with anything you want e.g. `0`

OUTPUT:

[image: out-2]

Comment: What is your IDE? Is it pycharm or something else?

Comment: @jezrael yes it is, just login with Google/Github and boom! > https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/5413dc5a-3d3b-4347-b88e-f8279c31c8e4/?m=Saved%20fiddle